# About the process of Date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, date

I have a question about the process of Date,

```
CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, I'm writing.
```

I want to list the datalies of today, but I could not do it.

> Databased: 2017-12-19 14: 46: 00.337

```
var notificationsList = _db.AllNotifications.Where (m => m.CreatedOn == DateTime.Today.Date) .ToList ();
```

Comment: What do you want to do with date..?
do you want to get only date in specific format or want to get time in specific format?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what goal you want to accomplish. Please edit your question.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is different from `DateTime.Today`.That is the cause of your problem.

Comment: "but I could not do it." What does that mean? What error/results do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list all the items which created today, you should disregard the actual time of day. for example:

```
    var notificationsList = _db.AllNotifications.Where (m => m.CreatedOn.Date == DateTime.Today.Date) .ToList ();
```

Or

```
    var notificationsList = _db.AllNotifications.Where (m => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.CreatedOn).Value.CompareTo(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Today)) == 0) .ToList ();
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to find all items that occur *at any time* today is to find the ones that happen on or after midnight today and *before* tomorrow:

```
var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
...
_db.AllNotifications.Where (m => m.CreatedOn >= DateTime.Today &&
                                 m.CreatedOn < tomorrow)
```

Comment: the following error has occurred.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @ArifÖZELCİ - move the tomorrow calculation out of line of the query and it should be okay.

Comment: thanks a lot,
what should I do when it says between two dates.